# android: json response is just a String

Tags: android, json

I know how to access to json. Now I get a json response like that:

```
"2014-02-16T20:27:54+00:00"
```

https://openligadb-json.heroku.com/api/last_change_date_by_league_saison?league_shortcut=bl1&league_saison=2013

this is not a JSONArray and has no Name. How can I access it?

Comment: remove first index and last index of your response and work with that

Comment: This is not a json response

Comment: accept as a string and then convert to date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not json formatted data. If you need it in json, you can generate it by yourself like this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("data", "2014-02-16T20:27:54+00:00" );
json.toString(); // { "data" : ""2014-02-16T20:27:54+00:00" } it is json
```

In other case you can work with this data as typical String. It depends on what you need to achieve.

Good luck!